# Do we need to delete session variables after user logout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-variables

In Ruby on Rails :

suppose I am having `session[:my_var] = 'my_val'`

So here my question is :
Do we need to set `session[:my_var]=nil` before user's sign-out?

or it will auto release the memory it has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby on Rails doesn't know what you want to keep or not when a user signs-out.

Say for example you have a `session[:language]` that is useful for every user, even anonymous ones. You wouldn't want to erase it to display the default language after the user has gone through the trouble of selecting one in particular.

So, delete the session objects you need to, like `session[:user]=nil` and keep the rest. If you have a lot of them to delete, make yourself a logout helper.

If you know you can swipe the whole session, use the `reset_session` like @adcosta said.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to clean your app session use reset_session.

If you only want to clean a var do session[:my_var]=nil

See [Sessions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000668) in rails

Answer (score 2):

If you have set up your authentication code properly, that should handle the release from memory. Here is how I did it in one of my apps:

```
#sessions_controller
  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to login_path, notice: 'Logged out'
  end
```